# How to remove noise data after dot/comma from data set using R 2.539544325400 ----> 2.53

Tags: r

let say we have this data set

```
I            W          X               Y               Z   
1        1.785714   0.71428570       78.428571       19.98857    
2       85.471429   2.8285714        1.285714       15.44857
```

I want to write code to keep just two or three numbers after dot/comma and remove the rest for the whole data set to become

```
I         W      X           Y           Z
1        1.78   0.71       78.42       19.98    
2       85.47   2.82        1.28       15.44
```

Please help me, 
THANK You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `floor()`, which rounds to the next lowest integer.

```
> floor(df1*100)/100
#  I     W    X     Y     Z
#1 1  1.78 0.71 78.42 19.98
#2 2 85.47 2.82  1.28 15.44
```

This works fine if you only have positive numbers. If you want to truncate the number after a certain digit, `trunc()` is preferable as it works for negative as well as for positive numbers:

```
> trunc(df1*100)/100
#  I     W    X     Y     Z
#1 1  1.78 0.71 78.42 19.98
#2 2 85.47 2.82  1.28 15.44
```

Here it gives the same result. The multiplication and division by 100 is used here to truncate the value after the second digit.

**data**

```
df1 <-read.table( text="I        W         X           Y            Z   
                        1   1.785714   0.71428570  78.428571    19.98857    
                        2  85.471429   2.8285714    1.285714    15.44857", header=T)
```

Comment: Why not use simply `round(x = ,digits = )` instead of `multiply and divide by 100`? Only caveat that the numbers be positive.

Comment: @Frash The function `round()` does not yield the same result. See for example value Z in row 1: `round(19.98857,2)` gives 19.99. This is not the desired output according to the OP (see also the title of the question)

Comment: @RHertel oops! missed that.